# The existence of a smooth functions taking values $0$ and $1$ on two given closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, global-analysis

In theorem 5.1 on page 39 Boothby's book(An introduction to Differentiable Manifolds By William M. Boothby), he prove that:

Let $F\subset \mathbb R^n$ be a closed set and $K\subset \mathbb R^n$ compact, $F\cap K=\varnothing$. Then there is a $C^{\infty}$ function $\sigma(x)$ whose domain is all of $\mathbb R^n$ and whose range of values is the closed interval $[0,1]$ such that $\sigma(x)\equiv1$ on $K$ and $\sigma(x)\equiv0$ on $F$.

In exercise 8 on page 40 he ask that:

In theorem 5.1, assume only that $K$ is closed. Does the theorem still hold?

I guess that the answer is yes. How can I prove this exercise (chapter II, section 5 exercise 8) throughout an elementary way without using of partition of unity?

Of course, he has expressed only the theorem 5.1 without saying about partition of unity. Is there any elementary way for answering to the exercise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you know the following fact?

> If $C \subset \mathbb R^n$ is closed there is a $C^\infty$ function $\phi_C$ with the property that $\phi_C \ge 0$ and $\phi_C(x) = 0$ if and only if $x \in C$?

You can define $$f(x) = \frac{\phi_K(x) - \phi_F(x)}{\phi_K(x) + \phi_F(x)}.$$
This function is $C^\infty$, equals $1$ on $K$, $-1$ on $F$, and is otherwise strictly in between $-1$ and $1$.

Now use $\sigma = \dfrac 12 (f+1)$.

Comment: I do not know this fact. How can I prove it?

Comment: In Boothby's book (page 39- 41) there is not nothing about your fact.

Comment: The only proof I know offhand uses a Whitney decomposition of the complement of $C$. I am looking at Boothby's book to see if he addresses it, but the result in Theorem 5.1 is rather weak. It doesn't require $F$ and $K$ to be equal to the sets where $\sigma$ takes the values $0$ and $1$, rather that they are contained in those sets.

Comment: Here is a reference: Proposition 2.3.4 in A primer of real analytic functions by Krantz and Parks.

Comment: Probably, May Boothby intend for an elementary way more than your fact?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what the intent of the exercise is.

Comment: We don't need Whitney to get the "fact". I gave a proof here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291965/let-a-b-subset-mathbbrn-open-sets-a-subset-b-how-can-i-set-a-function/1292021#1292021 For some reason this answer gets down voted; I rather like the proof.